# Why `byte & byte` need to be stored in an int

Tags: java, byte

As the title says, why do I need an int to store a `byte & byte` operation. For example,

```
byte a = -128;
byte d = -0x7f;
byte b = a & d; // <-- error - can't convert from int to byte
```

I think `8bit & 8bit = 8bit` Is that wrong?

Comment: Integer promotion. `byte b = (byte) (a & d);` Also, never post code as an image.

Comment: thank you !  
I just started using this site,and thanks for you help to change the answer!

Comment: There is no [tag:operator-keyword] in Java. Don't tag indiscriminately.